# UIDocumentInteractionController with own view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I have a popover with different possibilities to export data. My current goal is giving the user the ability to choose an application to open the exported data. For this reason i call `UIDocumentInteractionController`'s method:

```
- (BOOL)presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item 
                              animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

This works, but a popover that appears on top on another popover doesn't look very well. I want to push the list of external programs in that existing popover. Is this possible without much of stress?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, however you could dismiss your previous popover and then show the UIDocumentInteractionController from the same source